# View the console of a application running on a remote server

Tags: java, console, jconsole

I have an application which I can run locally via Putty. This lets me view and track activity on that application. I use the command below to execute the application:

```
java -jar my_server.jar
```

I would like to view the console of my application running on remote server. How would I do this?

Any pointers/help would be appropriated.

Comment: if you're using putty, it's being run remotelly, not locally, right? (or are you connecting to localhost?)

Comment: if you're using unix/linux and just want to keep track of the sysout and syserr, you can run your app directing these outputs to a file in a shared directory and, from your local machine, if you can mount the same shared directory, you can use tail -f. Now, if you need to interact with the app (like writing things from a prompt), I don't know how. Maybe there's some way using java agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not relate to either java or jconsole.

This is about terminal facilities. Putty is used to perform SSH connection. If the remote server is Unix like system you can use command `screen` to perform what you want. Take a look on Unix shell reference to learn how to use `screen`.